# How to configure Jenkins performance plugin to fail job with relative error threshold

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins pipeline script to run jmeter script and am using performance plugin to create performanceReport as below

```
performanceReport parsers: [[$class: 'JMeterParser', glob: "**/*.jtl"]], modeOfThreshold: true,relativeFailedThresholdNegative: 1.2, relativeFailedThresholdPositive: 1.89, relativeUnstableThresholdNegative: 1.8, relativeUnstableThresholdPositive: 1.5
```

In the below performance trend though errors are increased the build is green so I'm trying to configure Jenkins performance plugin to fail job if the percentage of errors increase by `X %` or response time decrease/increase by `X %`  with respect to previous build(s) . can someone please help me with it?

[image]

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this yet ?? As I would like to implement something similar

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest option for you is to wrap your JMeter tests using [TAURUS](https://gettaurus.org/kb/Basic1/) and use the Taurus [PASSFAIL](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=running-your-load-tests-with-pass-fail-criteria-a-guide) module to fail the job. In the PASSFAIL module I didn't see a way to compare the errors or response time across builds, but you can define the average RT/LT etc and make the job fail based on that. Hope that helps!